# How to access cabal/Setup.hs information from within my Haskell source files?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I need to use some `Cabal`-level information from within my Haskell `.hs` source files.

For example, obtaining the path to the `dist/` build directory ([`configDistPref`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-2.0.1.0/docs/Distribution-Simple-Setup.html#t:ConfigFlags); I don't want to hardcode `dist/`), so that I can look up some contents in it using `runIO` in `TemplateHaskell`.

From normal Haskell files, I don't seem to be able to access `Cabal`-level information.

What ways are there for me to bring that information from a custom `Setup.hs` file into my Haskell source files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Cabal and ghc have no out-of-the-box functionality from you to learn your `dist/` directory or similar info. Here are some approaches to do it manually:

## Solution 1: Serialising the entire Cabal information into a known place

One solution is shown by the [cabal-toolkit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-toolkit-0.0.4/docs/Distribution-Simple-Toolkit.html) library.

It gives you a hook modifier `userHooksWithBuildInfo :: UserHooks -> UserHooks` that you call in your `Setup.hs`, which serialises the `LocalBuildInfo` (which includes all important Cabal-level information, including `ConfigFlags{ configDistPref }`) into a dotfile (called `.lbi.buildinfo`) in the source directory.

It then provides a TemplateHaskell function `localBuildInfoTypedQ :: Q (TExp LocalBuildInfo)` which reads that file so that you can load the information in TH.

(I the Hackage version I linked above probably lacks an `addDependentFile` call [here](https://github.com/TerrorJack/cabal-toolkit/blob/513b634528611bba1516a332170825ec906a9dfc/src/Distribution/Simple/Toolkit.hs#L83) to notice when the serialised info changes, but the Github version already has a [fix](https://github.com/TerrorJack/cabal-toolkit/commit/fbffa0ac529747a390f9447a8b33c0571c331c73) for it).

---

However, if you'd like temp files like this to end up in the `dist/` directory, this also doesn't help (since as mentioned, the dotfile is in the toplevel of your project and you should add it e.g. to `.gitignore`).

## Solution 2: Passing specific information to GHC using `-D` flags

Via a [`confHook`](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-2.0.1.1/doc/API/Cabal/Distribution-Simple.html#g:2), that calls cabal configure with `"-ghc-options=-D__CPP_CABAL_DIST_DIR__=" ++ configDistPref`. Example for your `Setup.hs` file:

```
main = do
  defaultMainWithHooks $
    simpleUserHooks
      { confHook = \inputs configFlags@ConfigFlags{ configDistPref = configDistPref } -> do
          putStrLn "In Cabal configure hook"

          let distDir = fromFlagOrDefault "dist" configDistPref

          (confHook simpleUserHooks) inputs (configFlags{ configProgramArgs = ("ghc", ["-D__CPP_CABAL_DIST_DIR__=" ++ distDir]) : configProgramArgs configFlags })
      }
```

Then the only difficulty is to actually splice the `__CPP_CABAL_DIST_DIR__` macro into the code because you can't write `"__CPP_CABAL_DIST_DIR__"` in a Haskell String literal, that won't get substituted by CPP, so you have to use a string quasiquoter like [this one](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/raw-strings-qq-1.1/docs/Text-RawString-QQ.html), e.g. `[r|__CPP_CABAL_DIST_DIR__]` just to get that macro in; the usual way of doing CPP [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/cpp/Stringification.html) with `#__CPP_CABAL_DIST_DIR__` doesn't work in ghc's CPP, as explained [here](https://guide.aelve.com/haskell/cpp-vww0qd72):

> There are three main reasons why code with CPP might not work as expected:
>
> You used `#`, `##` or `__VA_ARGS__`. GHC runs CPP in traditional mode, which disables all advanced features.

## Solution 3: Passing specific information by generating a Haskell module with a preprocessor

You can add a `hookedPreProcessors` to your hooks in `Setup.hs`. In this hook you render as Haskell literals or strings any information from Cabal that you want to access.

An example on how to write a preprocessor can be found [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-2.0.1.0/docs/Distribution-Simple-PreProcess.html#t:PreProcessor) in the Cabal documentation, or even clearer, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16261412/263061).

Don't forget to add the module to be generated by your pre-processor to the `exposed-modules` or `other-modules` in your `.cabal` file, and put a file matching the preprocessor extension into your project, otherwise the preprocessor will not create the `.hs` file.

---

For my own use cases, I'm using **Solution 3** because it is clean, doesn't need any CPP or TemplateHaskell magic, gives good error messages and does not require the equivalent of `runhaskell Setup.hs configure` to run, `build` is enough because preprocessors are run at build time.